# 26er rims for a 26x1.95 tire?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, rims, compatibility

My rims are pretty old and I need help in buying a new ones. Can I use 26er rims for 26x1.95 tires?

Comment: All 26" rims designed for tires with a decimal width designation (vs a fraction such as 1-7/8) are the same diameter.  Within reason they will accept wider or narrower tires that also have a decimal width designation.  (Ie, the "ISO" number on such a tire should be "XX/599", where XX is the tire width in millimeters.)

Comment: Curious what that's a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @dlu - it's because this is a duplicate or low-value question and might be closed. No use writing an answer for such a question.